# Cassandra: How to paginate back from a 'n' th row key using RangeSlicesQuery?

Tags: pagination, cassandra

How to paginate back from a 'n' th row key using RangeSlicesQuery ?

The data is based on RandomPartitioner and the reverse option on the setRange function seems to be applicable only for the columns not on the rows. (http://tinyurl.com/73tncn3)

Example :

row_key1

row_key2

row_key3

row_key4

row_key5

row_key6

- Setting the endkey = row_key4, reverse = true & row count = 2 gives the following output.

**Expected :**

row_key3

row_key4

**Recieved :**

row_key1

row_key2

- Setting startkey = row_key4, reverse = true & row count = 2 gives the
  following output.

**Received**

row_key4

row_key5

Answer (score 1):

When using the RandomPartitioner, the effective order in which Cassandra store the rows is random.  Therefore you cannot do range slices in the way you expect.

What you should do is materialise your view in a row, and use some sort of calculated bucket for the row key. For example, the row key could be the the real row key / 10, and then the row could contain 10 real rows:

```
0 -> {row_key1 : v1, row_key2: v2, ...}
1 -> {row_key10: v10, row_key11: v11, ...}
and do on.
```

To do your query now, you do a get slice on row 0, from columns 'row_key4'...

Now you may ask, "what about my column keys"?  For this you should use compound column names.  For example, something that originally looked like this:

```
row_key1 -> {column1: v1, column2: v2, ...}
```

Would now look like this:

```
0 -> {[row_key1, column1]: v1, [row_key2, column2]: v2, ...}
and so on.
```

HTH

Tom